# How to use Django models ForeignKey?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I used two ForeignKey in Table 'Posts' to connect Table 'User', one is for username and another is for icon, like:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(UserInfo, related_name='user_name')
icon = models.ForeignKey(UserInfo, related_name='user_icon', null=True)
```

In my views, I try to iterate Table 'Posts':

```
class AllPosts(View):
    def get(self, request):
        all_posts = Posts.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'community.html', {
            "all_posts":all_posts,
            })
```

Here's how I iterate in my template:

```
{% for post in all_posts %}
<div class="post">
    <a href="" class="user_a">
    <img class="icon" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ post.icon }}">
    <span class="name_span">{{ post.user }}</span>
    </a>
    <span class="time">发表时间：{{ post.add_time }}</span>
    <span class="clicked">回复：{{ post.comment_num }}</span>
    <a href="">
    <img class="post_img" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ post.image }}">
    <div class="article">
    <h3 class="title">{{ post.title }}</h3>
    <span class="content">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp{{ post.content }}</span>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Results:

```
<img class="icon" src="/media/None">
<span class="name_span">klawens</span>
```

So the post.user show the correct result, but the icon is a None, I don't know how to use ForeignKey to connect the exact key I want, and what's the related_name for exactly?
The user field and icon field in 'Posts' both point the username in 'UserInfo', but I want the Posts icon point the UserInfo icon, how to do with that?

Comment: Your template code and the resulting HTML do not match. Please post actual code instead of hypothetical cases. Also, make sure that your `icon` field has actually any value. It is perfectly possible for it to return `None` as you set `null=True`.

Comment: I edited it, the user field and icon field in 'Posts'  both point the username in 'UserInfo', but I want the Posts icon point the UserInfo icon, how to do with that?

Comment: Do you mean that UserInfo class also has a icon column? For example, If your Model relationship like this `Class Post: icon=ForiegnKey(UserInfo) Class UserInfo: icon=CharField()`, you can simply do Post instance post.icon.icon.

Comment: please add your models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `{{ post.icon.icon }}` and `{{ post.user.username }}` not `{{ post.icon }}` or `{{ post.user }}`